# Alexa Skill keeps erroring saying "Cannot find module ./AlexaSkill"

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I've been trying to get it to work but it keeps coming up with the error 
mentioned in the title. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

The error I keep getting is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module './AlexaSkill'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:50:18)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)"
  ]
}
```

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/chris7990/3831d2aadc8cca6c2b46c60e3c1dbe35)

Answer (score 0):

`require('./AlexaSkill')` looks for a file by that name in the same directory as `index.js`. It looks like you copied that file into `index.js` (starting at line 127). Separate it into a file called `AlexaSkill.js`, or remove the `require` call.

Comment: Thanks for responding :) I've added it back into the original zip file with bot of the separate but it still says when I test it "The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid."

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Are you sure you configured the Skill and Lambda as documented?